# How to handle well-connected co-worker that wastes working hours on online Games?

Tags: management, colleagues

How to handle well-connected co-worker that wastes working hours on online Games?

I'm on a small software engineering team (5-7 people), who have an aggressive schedule.

I've noticed one team-member spends a tremendous amount of time at least 2-3 hours a day playing video games online and refuses to stop.
Management doesn't notice cause somehow we finish most of the work.

One workday I needed my coworker to finish his part (1 hour task) before I could progress forward with mine. My coworker took an entire day, and still did not complete the task

I decided I needed to stand next to his desk and walk this person through the process. Suddenly, I see a text from a manager (and long time friend of the coworker) to my coworker stating to go tell me to f$!ckoff because they were going to lose the game!

I got so angry! What can I do?
This manager has a direct line to my bosses boss!

This is BS. This person wastes so much time, goes home on-time every day, comes in late everyday, and never works after-hours.

What can I do? How can I tell this guy to get to work when he is friends with management?

Comment: Hey there ConfusedDeer, I think that the above linked question addresses your situation here, thus you may want to consider the advices there given. If you feel your situation is really different (not just in small details) please indicate so.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I disagree on this one.  Management already knows and is participating.  this is a different problem.

Comment: Ok, @RichardU perhaps not dupe but, If any, the post is related and still worth reading :)

Comment: @RichardU I think all or most of the advice there still applies. The fact that it's less likely to work doesn't really change the answer. The especially relevant part from that thread is: "It's your manager's job to manage" - if they don't want to manage, that's their issue. Also, I've played games with my boss (over lunch) but we worked hard the rest of the time - them playing together doesn't necessarily mean the lack of effort is visible here, so that post applies even more.

Comment: Why can't you leave on time? What's stopping you from saying, "Can't do it because Bob is playing games right now?"

Answer (score 0):

First off, always keep in mind that you are in the right in this situation. When you are standing next to him and see a "tell him to f off" text message, keep in mind that you are not the one doing wrong.

Second off, it is unlikely that your bosses boss will put up with this if they knew the truth. Therefore don't be too worried about them trying to drag your name through the mud because, again, you are in the right here. They likely won't want to bring the situation to a head because the truth will come out.

However it is unlikely you can do anything directly to get him to stop playing games and actually work. Don't stress over that, accept it. Just don't give an inch and remember that they are the ones wasting company time and being unreliable co-workers.